# Makingthe columns of a tableview fit the size of its contents

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have a tableview that looks like this

[image]

as you can see only the 3rd column is the right width while the first and second column are larger. Is there any way I could make the columns fit the content or explicitly make 1 and second columns smaller. I tried doing `tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();` but that makes no difference. Any suggestions ?

This is my code

```
void Test::AddEntry()
{
    QImage myimg;//(":/Test/Images/add.png");
    QStandardItem* item_avtr  =  new QStandardItem();
    item_avtr->setData( QPixmap::fromImage( myimg ), Qt::DecorationRole ) ;

    QStandardItem* item_aonline  =  new QStandardItem();
    item_aonline->setText("hello");

    QStandardItem* item_name  =  new QStandardItem("Name");


    QList<QStandardItem*> lst ;
    lst.push_back(item_avtr);
    lst.push_back(item_aonline);
    lst.push_back(item_name);

    ModelOptions->appendRow(lst);

}
```

The model is initiated like this

```
    ModelOptions =new QStandardItemModel();
ui.tableView->setModel(ModelOptions);
QStringList labels;

labels.push_back("col1");
labels.push_back("col2");
labels.push_back("col3");
ModelOptions->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels); 
ui.tableView->horizontalHeader()->setVisible(false);
ui.tableView->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
ui.tableView->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
ui.tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
ui.tableView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
AddEntry();
```

Comment: `resizeColumnsToContents()` should work just fine for this. There is likely something wrong with the way you're using it.

Comment: The code shows what I am doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `resizeColumnsToContents()` will only resize the columns once, depending on the *current* data of the table. So you should call it every time you change that data, i.e. at the end of `AddEntry()`. Data contained in the table but not currently shown in the viewport is *not* respected.
- `resizeColumnsToContents()` takes the width of horizontalHeaders into account, even if they are set invisible. Are they really named 'col1', 'col2' and 'col3' in your code?

Comment: Yes they are. Do the names of the columns matter ?

Comment: The width of the names do matter.

Answer (score 0):

ui.tableView->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents)

QHeaderView will automatically resize the section to its optimal size based on the contents of the entire column or row. The size cannot be changed by the user or programmatically. (This value was introduced in 4.2)

Comment: or do ui.tableView->resizeColumnsToContents(); after AddEntry();